# Bicycle box on train Gatwick to Reading

Tags: uk, public-transportation

Has anyone arrived on a flight into Gatwick Airport with a bike box and then got onto the train ? I arrive late at night from Australia and have booked a train ticket to Reading but booking space for a bike box is not available on this service. Should I get a cab ?

Comment: Once it's in a box you *probably* have to think in terms of bulky items rather than a bike (booked bike spaces on UK trains are bike racks). I suggest you get in touch with the train company directly (the ones I deal with are much more responsive on twitter than any other means of contact)

Comment: Aside - in the UK you'd want a taxi, not a cab.  But seriously, try asking the same question on http://travel.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Comment: @Criggie We call them cabs just as often as we call them taxis.

Answer (score 1):

I have once taken a boxed bike on a train from Bath to London airport. There wasn't really any space to put it somewhere, so I just put it upright next to one of the entrances and stood next to it for the ride. It wasn't a problem and noone complained about it. However, I also didn't ask anyone if it is legal or not.

Comment: There is no "London airport", though I guess it doesn't make much difference for the purpose of your answer whether you mean London City, Heathrow, Gatwick, Stansted or Luton.

Comment: In England you probably wouldn't get complaints :)

Comment: I know, I just forgot which one it was and I was to lazy to look up which of the airports it was.

Comment: Actually, it could make a difference which London airport it was, since travelling to the different airports requires using different train companies and they might have different luggage policies.